# Spotify Web API play endpoint - play track

Tags: spotify

I am trying to use the Spotify Web API to play a track when passed the track ID.  I am using the `PUT https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play` endpoint on Spotify's API Console [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/put-play/).  When I use the sample data in the `PUT` Body, and add my Device ID and OAuth token abd click the try it button, the song starts to play.  When I change the `PUT` Body to:

```
{
  "context_uri": "spotify:track:4ByEFOBuLXpCqvO1kw8Wdm"
}
```

I get the error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 99
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=600
Server: nginx
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 00:56:54 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Retry-After
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Non supported context uri"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the Spotify's API, `track` is not supported in the `context_uri`.

```
Optional. Spotify URI of the context to play.
Valid contexts are albums, artists & playlists.
Example: {context_uri:"spotify:album:1Je1IMUlBXcx1Fz0WE7oPT"}
```

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/start-a-users-playback/

Comment: ok, duh, thanks!!  I guess what threw me is below that it says you can send the optional `uris` of JSON array that appears to allow `spotify:track:...`

Answer (score 4):

if you pass:

```
{
  "uris": ["spotify:track:4ByEFOBuLXpCqvO1kw8Wdm"]
}
```

it will work. You could also, then pass multiple songs in the `uris` list.